# "Absolute" trackpad after update to 16.10

Tags: xorg, touchpad, 16.10

I just finished updating my ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10, and have a couple of issues, the most annoying being the new trackpad configuration.

When Xorg starts, the trackpad is using the absolute touch coordinates, like a graphics tablet.

Xorg.log says the following:

```
72.992] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/event7)
72.992] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
72.992] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
72.992] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
72.992] (**) evdev: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Device: "/dev/input/event7"
72.992] (--) evdev: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0xe
72.992] (--) evdev: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Found 1 mouse buttons
72.992] (--) evdev: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Found absolute axes
72.992] (--) evdev: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Found absolute multitouch axes
72.992] (--) evdev: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Found x and y absolute axes
72.993] (--) evdev: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Found absolute touchpad.
72.993] (II) evdev: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Configuring as touchpad
72.993] (**) evdev: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
72.993] (**) evdev: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
72.993] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6/event7"
72.993] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 15)
72.993] (II) evdev: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: initialized for absolute axes.
72.993] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
72.993] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 0
72.993] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
72.993] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
72.994] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
72.994] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
72.994] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

The system settings GUI has a single configuration tab for trackpad and mouse, so I don't know how to reconfigure it properly. Should I change the xorg.conf file? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

and reboot.

The user space driver was removed while upgrading for some reason.